# Safari doesn't fire click event on select element on time

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vue.js, safari

Chrome and Firefox fire click events on select element as the same time with opening its options menu but Safari doesn't fire an event until options menu closes.
I need click event to fire immediately on click, any workaround?

I tested on Safari 9 and 10.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hafez/nm3170v5/

```
<div id="app">
   <select @click="runTest($event)" v-model="selectedValue">
       <option value>select to check your browser</option>
       <option value="1">first</option>
       <option value="2">second</option>
   </select>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        selectedValue: ''
  },
  methods: {
    runTest(event) {
      if(event.target.value) {
        alert("It's too late to show an alert! I said on-clik stupid browser!");
      } else {
        alert("Alert on time! Good job dear browser!");
      }
      this.selectedValue = '';
    }
  }
})
```

*Note*: On my actual code, I have to `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` by using `click.stop.prevent` so the solution should satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `mousedown` instead of `click` ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erczzztf/)).

---

**NOTES**:

`click` afaik will fire the event upon releasing the mouse button whereas `mousedown` will fire the event upon depressing the mouse button. This might the reason for the delayed handler execution.

Comment: For some reason I have to use `click.stop.prevent` in my actual code and `mousdown.stop.prevent` prevents select to show its options menu. but your answer is acceptable for the raw issue.

Comment: Although I don't believe that it's true behavior for click handler to be delayed.

Comment: 1) consider using mouseup 2) consider wrapping the select in another element and stop the propagation that element.

Comment: @HafezDivandari I cannot help with your actual code unless you post it.  Do you have some complicated logic bound to `click` in your actual code?

Comment: @LinusBorg mouseup didn't work just like click. I couldn't make your second solution work on my fiddle, how is it possible to stop propagation on a wrapper element?

Comment: @FK82 Yes it is a complicate form, I'll try to summarize and post it. Thank you.